# Does Python include only 3 collection types?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Are these the only collection types in Python 3.x?

1. List
2. Sets
3. Dictionaries

From the documentation [Data Structures](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html)  section , there appear to be the only three.

Comment: Incidentally, that link points to the 2.x version.

Comment: Do strings count? Tuples? What about types not in the builtin module, ex. `collections.deque`?

Comment: Check out the `collections` [module](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/collections.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, Python supports more collection types. You missed the tuple, the deq, the string and bytes for example.

Actually the possibilities are infinite since you can make any object a collection by implementing some special methods and also you can subclass most built-in sequence times.

Answer (score 0):

Depends what you mean, "in".

Four have special status in Python, in that they have their own syntax at the language level. They are tuples `(x,...)`, lists `[x,...]`, sets `{ x, ...}`  and dicts `{'x':value,...}` (Five if you want to include strings as collections: I won't argue, but if you do, there's also Python 2 unicode making six)

I believe that the array module has special status at the interpreter level. Arrays are treated far more efficiently than lists. Is array.array is also special in that it's not called array.Array?  Most of the python number-crunching and data-analysis codes leverage it in their own object definitions.

You can define anything else you want as an object, inherit from the builtins,  or import other people's useful object definitions. The collections module is "blessed" in that it comes by default with Python ("batteries included") (as does array). collections also  includes a lot of mixin methods which may assist with building your own collection object.

Not really relevant, but why do so few people seem to know just how versatile the dict constructor is, and save themselves a lot of tedious punctuation or looping? Possibly, only because  of `{"k":"v",...}` syntax existing.

```
      x = dict( a=1, b='hello', **otherdict )
      y = dict( zip( keyslist, valueslist)) # [(key1,val1), (k2,val2), ...]
```

Comment: I won't cheat with edit. I missed out bytes (like strings: `b'...'` syntax).